# How to get first array in fetch promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I need to return in my fetch promise a JSON object which contains all my data. The issue is I don't know what the object name is. What I do know is that there will always be one object.

Here is me example code where I get what I need knowing the object name (in this case foo

```
  return fetch(endPoint)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => res.foo)
    .then(res => console.log(res))
```

My response would look like this

```
{
    "foo": [
        "bar1",
        "bar2",
        "bar3"
    ]
}
```

However my code would fail if this was the response:

```
{
    "goo": [
        "bar1",
        "bar2",
        "bar3"
    ]
}
```

How can I ensure my code always works no matter what the object is called?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.values`:

```js
const obj = {
  "foo": [
    "bar1",
    "bar2",
    "bar3"
  ]
};

const [foo] = Object.values(obj);
console.log(foo);
```

The above uses [*destructuring*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and it's shorthand for this:

```
const foo = Object.values(obj)[0];
```

---

Older syntax:

```js
var obj = {
    "foo": [
        "bar1",
        "bar2",
        "bar3"
    ]
};

var foo = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: you could also explain further, what you did there, maybe OP doesn't understand what destructuring is. (not the down voter)

Comment: Oh whoops, my bad @MaheerAli, I'll fix that.

Comment: Fixed now @MaheerAli, any better?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and access its first element.

```js
const obj = {"foo": ["bar1","bar2", "bar3"]}
const res = Object.values(obj)[0]
console.log(res)
```

You can make it even shorter using [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const obj = {"foo": ["bar1","bar2", "bar3"]}
const [res] = Object.values(obj)
console.log(res)
```